# Android Bindings Library creates an abstract class for an interface

Tags: c#, xamarin, interface, abstract-class, bindings-library

I am trying to create an Android Bindings Library for an *AAR* library.

Here is `IMessages`:

```
package my.package.messages;

public interface IMessages {
    public static final String SOME_STRING_1 = "somevalue1";
    public static final String SOME_STRING_2 = "somevalue2";

    void method1(Context paramContext);
    void method2(Context paramContext);
}
```

Here is what the generated code look like:

```
// Metadata.xml XPath interface reference: 
path="/api/package[@name='my.package.messages']/interface[@name='IMessages']"
[Register ("my/package/messages/IMessages", "", "My.Package.Messages.IMessagesInvoker")]
public partial interface IMessages : IJavaObject, IJavaPeerable {

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='my.package.messages']/interface[@name='IMessages']/method[@name='method1' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.content.Context']]"
    [Register ("method1", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V", "GetMethod1_Landroid_content_Context_Handler:My.Package.Messages.IMessagesInvoker, TestBindingLibrary")]
    void Method1(global::Android.Content.Context p0);

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='my.package.messages']/interface[@name='IMessages']/method[@name='method2' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.content.Context']]"
    [Register ("method2", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V", "GetMethod2_Landroid_content_Context_Handler:My.Package.Messages.IMessagesInvoker, TestBindingLibrary")]
    void Method2(global::Android.Content.Context p0);
}

[Register ("my/package/messages/IMessages", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
public abstract class Messages : Java.Lang.Object {

    internal Messages ()
    {
    }

    // NOTES: I assume this class is generated because interfaces can't have const fields in C# unlike Java
    // But this class is clashing with a "real" class named Messages

    // Metadata.xml XPath field reference: path="/api/package[@name='my.package.messages']/interface[@name='IMessages']/field[@name='SOME_STRING_1']"
    [Register ("SOME_STRING_1")]
    public const string SomeString1 = (string) "somevalue1";

    // Metadata.xml XPath field reference: path="/api/package[@name='my.package.messages']/interface[@name='IMessages']/field[@name='SOME_STRING_2']"
    [Register ("SOME_STRING_2")]
    public const string SomeString2 = (string) "somevalue2";
}
```

Now the issue is the *AAR* library contains a `Message` class, which gets generated like so:

```
// Metadata.xml XPath class reference: path="/api/package[@name='my.package.messages']/class[@name='Messages']"
[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("my/package/messages/Messages", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
public partial class Messages : global::Java.Lang.Object, global::My.Package.Messages.IMessages {

    // Metadata.xml XPath constructor reference: path="/api/package[@name='my.package.messages']/class[@name='Messages']/constructor[@name='Messages' and count(parameter)=0]"
    [Register (".ctor", "()V", "")]
    public unsafe Messages ()
        : base (IntPtr.Zero, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer)
    {
        // Omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Having both the abstract **Messages** class and the "real" one inheriting from the **IMessages** interface, I get the following error:

> Type 'Messages' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types

My question is, how can I alter the generation of the abstract class, so it doesn't clash with the "real" **Messages** class? I looked at [Metadata.xml Transform File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata#metadataxml-transform-file), but it's not clear to me what should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Try to take a look with "[Adding Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata#metadataxml-transform-file)" chapter.
There is an example what you should add to Metadata.xml:

```
<add-node path="/api/package[@name='my.package.messages']">
  <class abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" 
         name="Messages" static="false" visibility="public" extends="java.lang.Object"</class>
</add-node>
```

Comment: Isn't that supposed to add a class named `Messages`? I don't want to add it, it's already being generated automatically and clashing with another existing class named the same.

Comment: Just pay attention to abstract="false"  field. Also you could use <remove-node  path="/api/package[@name='my.package.messages']/class[@name='Messages']/constructor[@name='Messages' and count(parameter)=0]" />